# How to solve SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 INSERT error?

Tags: magento-1.9, sql

My website [oxyglowcosmetics.com](http://oxyglowcosmetics.com) was running fine But now it shows

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 INSERT command
>   denied to user 'oxyglow'@'182.50.130.126' for table 'lts_log_visitor'
>   ERROR

BOTH ON FRONTEND AND BACKEND.

[image: snapshot]

Comment: In hosting server, check this user `oxyglow` exists and has the correct password and privileges. O/w recreate/reset password and update `local.xml`

Comment: @Anil Suthar Thanks for your time, Yes it exists. Sorry, But how to check privileges the user oxyglow from phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your database is full.

Thus MySQL cannot add more rows to your log tables.

Check your database size and limit. I suggest you enable automatic log cleaning in the configuration that'll avoid keeping very old logs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Currently I am not able to login into admin panel of my magento website, the same error shows. So, Any other way to clean my database?

Comment: @aseem access directly the database via phpmyadmin or directly via the console

Comment: @AseemAkash You can also use Adminer if phpmyadmin not works. Link: https://www.adminer.org/